# Node Js + JSON to Excel with inner json content

Tags: json, node.js, excel

I tried to convert json to excel conversion using node module ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2xls )

I attached my sample json file:

```
[ { "id":11, "title":"The Brain ", "keyTerms":"You should a", "visible":true, "introduction":{ "id":5336, "title":"Introductory Materials", "resources":[ { "id":22, "title":"Vocabulary - Brain and Nervous System", "description":""} ] }, "objectives":[ { "id":33, "title":"1. Describe how the nervous system is organized", "caContribution":5, "position":1, "resources":[ { "id":23024, "title":"Reading - How the Nervous System Works"} ] } ] } ]
```

Getting excel output:

Heading: 
1.id, 
2.title,
3.keyterms,
4.visible,
5.introudction,
6.objectives

and results getting but the problem is inside the introduction and objectives column values getting only **[object][object],[object][object]**

Expected Output:

Inside the all json object should be come as title with value.

Comment: Given your sample JSON, what do you expect to be the value contained in the `introduction` column?

Comment: @JackZelig - I added my sample json file. please check here. https://jsfiddle.net/rajinikumarr/oyn5a397/

Comment: Thanks, but that still doesn't answer my question :)

Answer (score 0):

You could add these two lines:

```
jsonObject[0].introduction = jsonObject[0].introduction.title;
jsonObject[0].objectives = jsonObject[0].objectives[0].title;
```

where `jsonObject` contains your json.

This will of course only work for the first element in your array, and it only selects the title of the first objective. If you're importing more than one row and / or objective you have to write some additional logic.